# Derailer/hanger for Cannondale Jekyll

Tags: derailleur-rear

As I've mentioned before, I volunteer with a group called "Pedal it Forward" (under the auspices of the local Kiwanis club) to rehab donated bikes.  Most (discounting those that are already scrap when they come in) are given (after rehab) to "Christmas Anonymous" and other charitable causes, but when we get a really nice one we sometimes sell it to help pay for operating expenses.

We currently have a really clean, nice looking Cannondale Jekyll 26" full-suspension bike with aluminum frame.  The only problem with it is that it's completely missing it's rear derailer and hanger.  Apparently the parts were damaged, the owner took them off, and, couple of years later, donated the bike to get it out of his garage.

So, where would I find a derailer (and, more importantly, a hanger) to fit this bike?

I would guess the bike is about 5 years old.  "CAAD4" is printed on the side.  It has 2 speeds front, 9 speeds rear.  Disk brakes.  The front mech is Shimano Deore XT.

Serial number:

```
556284LK02351
IDMNJN    LG
```

Pictures:
[image]
[image]
[image]

So any idea where to find an appropriate hanger and derailer (or at least a clue as to what is "appropriate")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wheelsmfg.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/299x299/06866988214b6a9b717ef7211319fd38/d/r/dropout-16.300px.jpg
I think it may be this one (Wheels Manufacturing #16). Is there a broken bolt in the hole just above the rear axle? You will need to find a way to get that out to be able to mount the hanger properly.

For a derailleur, it would be nice to match it with the front, so look for a 9-speed Shimano XT. Try to avoid low-normal (Shimano calls it rapid-rise) derailleurs. Any Shimano 9-speed mountain bike derailleur will work (Deore, LX, XT, XTR). I wouldn't go below the Deore level to keep similar quality level for all components.

[image]

Comment: Yep, Wheels #16 was it.  The broken bolt came out easily.  Installation was fairly smooth, though I had to very lightly file the rough spots off the back side of the dropout to get the unit to fit -- it was *very* snug.  Elsewhere I figured out it was a Shimano Deore RD-M591 derailer.  Some cussing was involved in fitting the new chain, given we didn't have the old one to measure.

Comment: cussing is scientifically proven to help.